# Java Regex puzzle

Tags: java, regex

How do you use a single regex expression that splits all of the following text in Java.

```
<ab>::=<cd> <ef>|<gh>              => ['<ab>', '<cd> <ef>', '<gh>']
<ri>::=hello|nope|we|super         => ['<ri>', 'hello', 'nope', 'we', 'super']
<ri>::= hello | nope  | we |super  => ['<ri>', 'hello', 'nope', 'we', 'super']
```

Comment: You could split on everything different from `a-z`, `<`, `>`.

Comment: but then i dont want to split <cd> <ef> these two apart@BackSlash

Comment: Just split on `::=` and `|`?

Comment: @TianchengXu There is a space between them, it will work.

Comment: Include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Rawing in the comments you can split on `::=` and on the pipe symbol. To make sure you directly trim the spaces I suggest something like this: `\s*\|\s*`. This matches `|` with any amount of whitespaces before and after it which includes spaces. So when split on that, the spaces will be removed as well.

Now to combine them you put them in a capture group and seperate them with an or:

`(::=|\s*\|\s*)`

See what is captured by this group [here](https://regex101.com/r/lJPVEQ/1)
The green marked ones are the parts where it is split and the "normal" parts are the ones that will be the result of splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be ok?

It only catches words or words within brackets

```
/\w+|<\w+>/g
```

Comment: Note that `\w` also matches  `_` and `0-9`. [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html)

Comment: Yes but I don't know if OP only wants letters or also numbers. It would be /\[a-zA-Z]+|<\[a-zA-Z]+>/g in that case

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.split`

```
string.split("\\s*(?:::=|\\|)\\s*")
```

This would split the string on `::=` or `|` with the spaces covered up.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uXL7gs/1)